# How to pass a POST request with Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, post, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to Google Cloud Functions service. I read the docs but still have some small basic questions. I'm trying to create a function which gets a POST requests (using a webhooks) and makes a POST requests (after parsing the received data).

Using webhooks, my website sends data in JSON:

```
{
  "post": {
    "id": 587,
    "topic_title": "Test",
    "admin": false,
    "category": "8-category"
  }
}
```

I know how to parse JSON but I'm having trouble figuring out how can I get it and how to POST it (for example for: `https://test.test`).

I would be glad to see the most basic example - getting data and passing it with a POST request (I'll add the parsing part myself).

Comment: There are lots of official samples.  https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/

Answer (score 1):

Don't be disturbed by the Cloud Function service, it's only the underlying infrastructure. Your function and your request handling is exactly the same!

The JSON sent in the POST request is in the body of the request object. Then, perform your process, and finally don't forget to reply a 2XX HTTP return code for correctly ending your call. Also, think about security if your function publicly exposed (but it's the same thing if you deploy on premise, Cloud Functions doesn't change the recommendation and the best practices).

As mentioned by Doug you can find a lot of examples in several languages.